# how to rename an existing database in MySQL localhost

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to know how to rename an existing DB locally.
I use XAMPP and myPHPyadmin as the MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLyog, there is an option to copy the database to another host/database, not sure in myphpadmin but anyways you can dump the database to sql scripts, edit the scripts to change the name of the database, create the new database and load the scripts.

Answer (score 5):

PHPMyAdmin has an option to rename a database:

[image]